# ASP: Image containing charts does not seems to loads

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a web site with asp.net and C#. I have 6 ASP charts that seems to be loading on one computer but not on others: I published the website on a server through IIS7. When accessing it from my computer (IE9) it works. But not chart images are loading from other computers: I am getting a big red X instead.

On my web.config these are my settings:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ChartHttpHandler" value="Storage=memory;Timeout=180;"/>
</appSettings>
```

I tried to change the value of the storage to file or session but nothing change. I changed the timeout to be 2000 but with no luck.I also added ;privateImages=false; but with no luck either.

I also have the following under handlers in the web.config

```
<add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is a mime type issue , is this possible if you can check mime type is added in other computer to render images. You can go to IIS and then in righ side there is an option "Mime Type" click on that and then you can see image extension are added there or not.

Comment: Sorry! I was not very clear: Some charts are loading and some are not on the new computer. And it is not always the same: always 3 out of 6.

Comment: any javascript error while page load ?

Comment: No I am not getting any JS error either on IE or Firefox

Comment: Is there a limit for the number of charts you can have on an asp page? I have 6